# Changing db schema django based heroku

Tags: python, django, heroku, django-models, heroku-postgres

I am adding a field to my existing Django model and when I push it to Heroku the new field didn't add and it shows an error : column [new field] does not exist. What did I miss?
I did migrate it and the new field added in local Django but it's not changing in Heroku

```
column quizTest_responden.nohp does not exist
LINE 1: ...st_responden"."job", "quizTest_responden"."jobg", "quizTest_...
```

Comment: Have you run the migrations locally and in your heroku environment? That error suggests that the migrations haven't been run for your heroku database.

Comment: yes i did make migrations locally. doing it in my heroku environment solve the problem though. Strange that the other day i did migrate locally, push the migrations file and heroku did it automatically, now for some reason i need to do it twice.